# using sqlite in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I want perform a easy task in android, which when receiving a call the phonenumber will be matched to a number in my database. However I already read that sqlite  and BroadcastReceiver are not that easy to combine. Below is the code:

```
public class incomingcall extends BroadcastReceiver{

        String caller;
        Cursor c;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                sqlitedatabase search = new sqlitedatabase(context);

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 

                if(null == bundle)
                        return;

                Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

                String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

                if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                {
                        String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

                        try{

                            search.open();

                            c = search.callinfo(phonenumber);

                            if(c != null){

                                int iFN = c.getColumnIndex("firstname");
                                int iLN = c.getColumnIndex("lastname");
                                String FN = c.getString(iFN);
                                String LN = c.getString(iLN);
                                caller = FN + " " + LN;
                            }
                            else{

                                caller = "Unknown";
                            }

                            search.close();
                         }

                        catch (Exception e){

                            Toast.makeText(context, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(context, caller, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
}
```

I don't think the problem lies with the methode ".callinfo()", nonetheless I posted it below:

```
public Cursor callinfo(String l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{"phonenumber", "homenumber"};
        Cursor c = db.query("mycontacts", columns, "phonenumber = " + l + " OR " + "homenumber = " + l, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }
```

The Catch returns : errorandroid.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the initial cursor position is -1, try to use `if(c.moveToNext())` instead of `if(c != null)`.

Comment: Cursor.moveToNext() answers a boolean which is true if the move succeeded.

Comment: Thank you to both you. You answer was correct and it works. This is one of the disadvantages of being a beginnner (not seeing the a logical mistake). Thank you for answering so fast.